# cornerRadius for UILabel using User Defined Runtime Attributes not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I try to add cornerRadius to UILabel using `User Defined Runtime Attributes` 
But it is not working as expected, cornerRadius is not setting and I wonder where I made mistake. I attached screenshot of it,

[image]

Help me out in solving

Comment: Sorry uploaded wrong image,updated

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is `layer.cornerRadius` not just `cornerRadius` also you need to set `layer.masksToBounds` to `true`.

[image]

Comment: Also set `layer.masksToBounds` property with boolean value `true`.

Comment: @WillForte Check the edited answer you get idea about it.

Comment: but I didn't set it for button and views, those work fine.

Comment: @WillForte Have you try once by setting `masksToBounds` property?

Answer (score 9):

Create extension to set corner radius from storyboard

[image]

```
public extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get { return layer.cornerRadius }
        set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Create a category of UIView
In .h file
///Below interface
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *borderColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;

In .m file
//below Implementation
@dynamic borderColor,borderWidth,cornerRadius;


-(void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor{
    [self.layer setBorderColor:borderColor.CGColor];
}

-(void)setBorderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth{
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
}

-(void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius{
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:cornerRadius];
}
```

//Now you can set if from the Attribute Inspector